# How to import socket.io-client using systemjs?

Tags: typescript, socket.io, systemjs

How do I import the standalone socket.io client? I'm using system.js as the module loader and I write my code in typescript.

In my typescript file I have the following import statement.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

The configuration of system.js looks like this.

```
   System.config({
    map: {
        rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'socket.io-client': 'node_modules/socket.io-client'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {defaultExtension: 'js'},
      'socket.io-client': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

In my browser I get this error.

> angular2-polyfills.js:126 GET
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/socket.io-client/ 404 (Not Found)

What do I have to do to load this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify a full path to socket.io.js like below

```
System.config({
map: {
    rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'socket.io-client': 'node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js'
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.config({
map: {
    ...
    "socket.io-client": "npm:socket.io-client/dist"
},
...
packages: {
    ...
    "socket.io-client": {"main": "./socket.io.js"}
}
});
```